# Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl section 2.2.1 A User Tour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app

I am really new to programming and I am currently working through the toy_app in chapter 2 of the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl and can't seem to figure out how to access the pages created by the "rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string" and "rails db:migrate" commands.

I am using cloud9 through AWS so the book doesn't match completely.

After I ran the "rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string" and "rails db:migrate" commands, I went ahead and ran the local webserver in a separate tab as the book suggests with the "-b $IP -p $PORT" command since I'm using the cloud IDE.

I understand that I have to include "/users" to the root URL as the book suggests in order to get the corresponding page to reflect on the browser rather than just "hello, world!" but I cannot seem to be able to locate the "root URL". I have tried adding "/users" to the URL given to me by the "heroku create" command but all I receive is "The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved" after doing so.

I assume that I am using the wrong URL but I cannot seem to find the one the book is talking about. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That seems hell of  a lot more complicated then just running it on your own machine/VM/docker - especially since its just a throwaway that you're done with in the next chapter.

Comment: Don't try to solve or learn everything at the same time. Just boot up a local Rails server with `rails s` and learn all this other stuff later or separately.

Comment: I found the correct URL, finally! I first thought that I had to plug  " /users " into the URL given by the `heroku create` command but all I had to do is run the server in the cloud IDE and hit "preview" and plug " /users " into the URL of the window that was opened after previewing.